# How difficult would it be to build a Chat/IM Client for an office network?

Tags: vb.net, networking, chat

First and foremost, I would like to say I am very, /very/ new to programming and the like. If I decide to build this, this would probably be my first "large" project i've ever done myself.

What I am looking to build is a very simple Chat/IM client to use for the users in our office network. It would just call us their Windows logon name and use that to IM and the like. I'm talking a very simple client, with a list of names of people who are logged into the network, and option to IM them and an option to do a multiple user chat. It doesn't have to be visually stunning.

How difficult would this honestly be? Is it possible for me, someone who has very little knowledge when it comes to programming to teach myself how to build it?

If not, can you explain why this would be very difficult and what already built clients would work well for what I am using?

Comment: That's complex. It involves networking, concurrency, security. Since you say you are very inexperienced, I would recommend you pick a smaller project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big application. Your first parts will suck and refactoring it later will suck even more. I suggest building something small in the first place and then step from one bigger project to another.

XMPP/Jabber is IMHO the best solution for office IM. Most clients like Pidgin, Adium etc can connect to it. Every bigger company I worked for in the last years used it. Take a look at Openfire - A free open source XMPP server that you can directly connect on and which is easy to set up: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Comment: I actually have been playing around with this all day. This could be exactly what i'll be implementing.